# what is Max operating temperature of TASSIMO Bosch My Way

Tags: machine-code

Having read the articles regarding changes to barcodes on Tassimo Coffee Machines, I was wanting to know if the water temperature could be changed to a hotter setting if possible via the barcodes.
Unfortunately I am not experienced in editing code as described.

Thanks for your time.
Kind regards
Ivor Mac